# Check database for duplicates

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a doctors booking system.

I have a user name text box, a time drop down menu, doctor name text box and a date calendar control. All the values are sent to a database in 4 different fields.

I need to find a way to check if the time, date, and doctor are already booked so the system wont allow double bookings.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: This question is far too broad as posted. If you have a specific (few) lines of code that you're having trouble with, post that and detail exactly what the problem is (*it doesn't work* is not enough detail)

Comment: I think you are expecting that someone else make your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid duplicates by couple of ways

1. use unique key constraint
2. check if record already exist by doing select * from